# How to fix a CORB error generated by a URL called by .get() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a problem when calling a URL with jquery. It works fine in IE but in Chrome and Firefox, I get an error message.

I'm opening the HTML file from my computer, and I need either Firefox or Chrome to work for a testing purpose.

I've tried opening Chrome with a commandline, I've downloaded an Addon to prevent a CORS error I was getting.

I've also tried turning the "get" methods into getJSON, I didn't get CORB errors anymore, but the code in the .done functions didn't work on Chrome and Firefox (it did work on IE though). I've put "&callback=?" at the end of the URLs (while still using getJSON function) but nothing changed.

Here's the code:

```
$.get(URL1)
        .done(function(data){
        $(data["projects"]).each(function(l){
            arrProjDev[l]=data["projects"][l];
        })
        $.get(URL2)
        .done(function(response){
            $(response["result"]).each(function(m){
                arrTaskDev[m]= response["result"][m];
            })
            $.get(URL3)
            .done(function(responseTr){ 
                $(responseTr["result"]).each(function(n){        
                    arrTriggDev[n]=responseTr["result"][n];
             })
```

Each URL returns a JSON object.

A tree view is supposed to appear in a specific div, and heach row is an object contained in the JSON files.

But when I try to open the app in Chrome, I get this error message:

jquery.min.js:4 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://URL with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

In firefox, it's more complicated, the error message is in french but it says that a Cross-Origin Request was blocked and that "same origin" politics doesnt allow me the browser to open the URL because the CORS header  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin " is missing.

It looks a lot like the problem I've already solved in Chrome with the addon but I can't solve it on firefox.